# How to derive a column in a table based on values from one or two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, powerbi

I have a table with the following columns:
*Account Number* and *Cost Center*.

I want to create a new column called *Target Account* which is based on the derivation of these two. I already have that mapping. For example:

```
Account numbers
10000*
10010*
10020*
10030*
10040*
10080*
```

are all mapped to Target 1110

Similarly,

```
10050*
10060*
10070*
10095*
```

are all mapped to Target 1115. I need to first figure out how to create this mapping.

After this it gets a little complicated, because *Cost Center* comes into picture for few records.

For example based on the combination of *Account* and *Cost Center*, we have the following mapping of Target as shown in the link below:

[image: Mapping1]

Similarly, we have:

[image: Mapping2]

And so on...

Can somebody please help me to create this mapping in SQL or Excel or PowerBi?

Comment: Probably nested CASEs.

Comment: I thought that too, but there are almost 45-50 such unique Target Accounts and ofcourse , a lot more number of Account Numbers...

Comment: Can you apply `CASE WHEN col LIKE ...`?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-off exercise (e.g. data migration), then honestly, I would create the complete, detailed mapping table for each source account number and cost center combination. A simple join on this mapping table would provide you with the target account number.

If this is a recurring exercise (e.g. reporting by different accounting standards) and managing the complete detailed mapping table would be too cumbersome, then I would create patterns in the mapping table using % or _ characters. In this case also a simple join on the mapping table would give you the desired target account number, but this time I would use `like` operator to map the source data to the target.

Comment: Its just for easy access, because these Target Account numbers are stored in another organization database and they have an income statement associated with them, we want to be able to directly see these income statement in our project and database table i.e. associating Account Number with Income through Target Account. I have them in mapping in an excel sheet but I want to create a rule in Excel preferably so that when I pull these Account numbers and Cost Center from my database then through that rule, I also get those Target Account numbers.

Comment: The same applies in excel as well, just in excel create a mapping column where you have the source account number and cost center separated by another character to be able to use vlookup for the mapping. You can use the first n characters from the account numbers / cost center codes with the left function.